# Check return code in bash while capturing text

Tags: bash, if-statement, output, conditional-statements

When running an ldapsearch we get a return code indicating success or failure. This way we can use an if statement to check success.

On failure when using debug it prints if the cert validation failed. How can I capture the output of the command while checking the sucess or failure of ldapsearch?

```
ldapIP=`nslookup corpadssl.glb.intel.com | awk '/^Address: / { print $2 }' | cut -d' ' -f2`
server=`nslookup $ldapIP |  awk -F"= " '/name/{print $2}'`
ldap='ldapsearch -x -d8 -H "ldaps://$ldapIP" -b "dc=corp,dc=xxxxx,dc=com" -D "name@am.corp.com" -w "366676" (mailNickname=sdent)"'
while true; do
    if [[ $ldap ]] <-- capture text output here ??
    then
        :
    else
        echo $server        $ldapIP     `date` >> fail.txt
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: Check `$?` after `ldapsearch`.

Comment: BTW, storing a command in a string is very bad practice. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and (re: `eval`) [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). If you don't **mean** to be storing the command's text in the string, but only mean to be storing its output, then... well, that's a whole different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @codeforester suggested, you can use `$?` to check the return code of the last command.

```
ldapIP=`nslookup corpadssl.glb.intel.com | awk '/^Address: / { print $2 }' | cut -d' ' -f2`
server=`nslookup $ldapIP |  awk -F"= " '/name/{print $2}'`
while true; do
    captured=$(ldapsearch -x -d8 -H "ldaps://$ldapIP" -b "dc=corp,dc=xxxxx,dc=com" -D "name@am.corp.com" -w "366676" "(mailNickname=sdent)")
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "${captured}"
    else
        echo "$server        $ldapIP     `date`" >> fail.txt
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

EDIT: at @rici suggestion (and because I forgot to do it)... ldap needs to be run before the if.

EDIT2: at @Charles Duffy suggestion (we will get there), we don't need to store the command in a variable.

Comment: That won't work. The last command executed before `$?` is `true` (from the while loop), which always succeeds. I think you need to actually invoke the ldap command somewhere.

Comment: Why are we storing the command in a string and then invoking `eval` at all, instead of just running the command directly? We're adding vulnerabilities here (if someone can replace the DNS entry for `ldapIP` with a `TXT` record, they can run arbitrary commands on the server due to the `eval`), and getting no benefit.

Comment: Consider if your `nslookup` comes back with a result where the second word found contains `$(IFS=,;rm,-rf,$HOME)`. If you didn't use `eval`, that would be harmless, but as it is...

Comment: ...btw, it'd be much better to quote your expansions for echo; `echo "$captured"` -- that way whitespace, &c. is unmolested. Same for `echo "$server       $ldapIP     $(date)"`.

Comment: BTW, you could also do `if captured=$(...); then` all on one line, and not need to check `$?` at all.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with the `$?` thing, let's say it's informative, like in: that's how you can do it...

Comment: Understood -- the caveat is that it's fragile: If someone adds more logging (ie. `echo "DEBUG: completed ldapsearch" >&2`), then that changes `$?`, so all of a sudden the `if` is branching wrong despite not changing anything in the `if` itself. That's why when I use `$?`, I actually store it as a continuation of the line where it's assigned (`foo; foo_rc=$?`, and then referring to `$foo_rc` on future lines).